# Dynamically import a python file whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: python, python-import

I have 2 python scripts. First python script name is
`"test_1.py"`
and internally it has `main()` function, and second script is
`"test_2.py"`
and internally it has a method called `"sub_main()"`.
Like wise I can have

```
test_3.py, test_4.py etc
```

Now in my `"test_1.py` I am trying to import `"test_2.py"` dynamically i.e the user will send the file name in command line arguments and I will store it in a variable and using this variable I should be able to import that respective script and call the "sub_main()" in my "main()" method of `"test_1.py".`
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: i think it's an x y [problem](https://xyproblem.info/)  i think  the real question is why do you need those dynamic imports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import importlib

module_name = input('Enter a module name you want')
dynamically_imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the name of the module you want to import from the command line arguments, put it into a variable, use that in an f string and `exec()` that f string:

```
st = f"import {name_of_module_to_be_imported}"
exec(st)
```

Whether that is a good idea is, of course, another question. You're opening yourself up to all sorts of security exploits where somebody could inject malicious code into the command-line arguments, which you will then execute.